# HTML and CSS possibilities when wrappeded inside 'select' tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, xhtml

I need to display options present in a select region (allowing multiple select) in form of tree. This tree needs to be collapsible/expandable. I have implemented it such that it looks and works as intended in FF.

```
 - 1
   - 1.1
     + 1.1.1
     - 1.1.2
       - 1.1.2.1
       - 1.1.2.2
       - 1.1.2.3
     + 1.1.3
```

I have achieved this by styling `<option>` tag with left padding and a google-like '+' '-' background. The JS for collapsing et al in done using jQuery.

But in IE things look as if no changes had been made and the JS does not work either :|

```
 1
 1.1
 1.1.1
 1.1.2
 1.1.2.1
 1.1.2.2
 1.1.2.3
 1.1.3
```

Does IE not allow attaching padding, backgound etc to `<option>` tags? How can I do this differently?

It is not possible to not support this work on IE6. Saving the debate on that for later ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Styling [<option>s in IE is quite limited](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-291-no-styling-options-in-ie.html). I'm afraid you won't find any solution using the <select> element as your container.

In brief:

- no padding
- no background images
- no event handlers (onclick, onkeypress, etc.)

IE (5,6,7,8) only support changing the text color, background color and font of the option elements.

There is a [jQueryUI Tree](http://jqueryui.pbworks.com/Tree) in development and various implementations out there for jQuery already.  I would highly recommend using one of them. (PS most of them use the UL, LI tags to form the structure)

I quite like this one. "[jQuery File Tree](http://abeautifulsite.net/notebook/58)"

Comment: Like your answer the best. You confirmed what I was afraid I might have to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a rich combobox widget. ExtJS ([You can find it here](http://extjs.com)) is a very good widget library and they have great support on their forums.

Answer (score 0):

Styling form controls is very problematic. The only way to achieve browser consistency is to replace form elements with regular elements like styled `div`s.

This [jQuery click menu](http://p.sohei.org/jquery-plugins/clickmenu/) plugin might be useful, you can use it to set a hidden input on click.

Comment: Hmm.. Hidden inputs will have to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you really looking for a multi-level accordion script ? That's what accordions do, they expand and collapse.

Comment: No. There is quite a lot of difference. I need a tree like list.